# Stored procedure to apply pagination on table(input parameter to stored procedure) in oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g, pagination, oracle10g

I have to create a stored procedure in Oracle to apply pagination on a table where I will pass the datatable or xml string variable as a input parameter to my stored procedure, and then it will get stored in the temporary table and then pagination gets applied on the table.

Does anyone have any references and links about pagination on xml string or datatable? Please share or if anyone already implemented such a pagination approach on Oracle db, please share link and references

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand the question.  A DataTable is probably some sort of class that is implemented either in your middle tier (if we're talking the .Net DataTable) or in your front end (if we're talking the jQuery plug-in).  As such, it doesn't make sense as a parameter to a database stored procedure.  That leaves passing in an XML document but then it's unclear what you want the procedure to do with the XML.  What does that XML document represent?  The data you want to return?  The query you want to run?  Something else?

Comment: hi justin i have to pass xml string(of table)  as a input parameter to store procedure and i have to apply pagination to xml string(table) and want to return table content as per its index value in pager.